# Is this a compact manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness

Consider $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. My very short, and hopefully not too stupid question is, if $X$ is a compact manifold.

I think compact is clear by Tychonoff's theorem, but I do not think its a manifold.

Comment: any discrete space (with the discrete topology) is a 0-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Which would be the dimension of the manifold?

Comment: $X$ is totally disconnected, but has no isolated points. Hence it's not a manifold.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hence a diffeomorphism $f\colon X\to X$ cannot be an *Axiom A diffeomorphism* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_A), even if both conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: No nonempty open subset of $X$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of some $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $X$ is not even a topological manifold. We don't have a differentiable structure on $X$, so it doesn't make sense to speak of a diffeomorphism $f\colon X \to X$.

Comment: You are right, The big context is that for some dynamics, I am searching for a measure of max. entropy and for Axiom A systems its possible to find such a measure. But, of course, f is no diffeomorhpism...

Comment: The space $X$ is homeomorphic to the usual middle-thirds Cantor set. Indeed, any compact, totally disconnected, perfect, metrizable space is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Comment: A Cantor set such as $X$, although not a manifold, could well occur as a basic set of an Axiom A diffeomorphism. A typical example is the basic set of the Smale horseshoe. Since the interesting invariant measures for Axiom A diffeomorphisms are supported on basic sets, your "big context" is perfectly appropriate, despite the difficulties of speaking of "diffeomorphisms" on $X$.

Comment: @LeeMosher X is a Cantor set? Sorry, I am not familiar with the notion Cantor set. Moreover, I dont know if f is a diffeomorphism: f is defined by $f(1)=2, f(2)=0$ and $f(0)=1$ if one of its neighbots is 1, otherwise $f(0)=0$:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set

Comment: Ok, maybe I should add some details. The context is the following. $f\colon X\to X$ describes the dynamics (as I described in my last comment). I found that the non-wandering set $\Omega(f)$ is a global attractor and, moreover, every point in this attractor has finite many pre-images. Now, I am wondering whether there is a measure of maximal entropy.  - This is how I came to Axiom A systems. But maybe there are other theorems that tell me sth. about the existence/ construction of measure of max. entropy. Anyway, f is no diffeomorphism (but maybe I do not need that).

Comment: At this point, perhaps you have material for a different question.